# Why does creating a Cloud Function automatically deploy a Cloud Run Service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a Cloud Function to be triggered through Pub/Sub Eventarc trigger by Push. Once I deploy the Function, it automatically deploys a Cloud Run.

In the Cloud Function Action's dropdown menu, I can see "Go to Cloud Run service", which is available only for that specific function.

So, why this behavior? Is possible the Function works with Pub/Sub Push trigger without a Cloud Run Service associated?

**Cloud Run**
[image]

**Cloud Function**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running a 2nd gen Cloud Functions, which means that it is built on top of Cloud Run. From the [Cloud Functions version comparison](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison):

> Cloud Functions offers two product versions: Cloud Functions (1st gen), the original version, and Cloud Functions (2nd gen), a new version built on Cloud Run and Eventarc to provide an enhanced feature set.

So Cloud Functions 2nd gen uses a Cloud Run container to run your code, which is why you see that service being used in the console too.